# Divide a specific row into multiple cells within a table: Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word VBA, I want to create a table which has a variable number of columns per row,

Depending on the desired number of cells per row, the number of cells per row can change.

A possible solution would be to allow to split the desired row (numRow) into the entered number of cells (nbAttrCellToCreate) as follows:

`nbAttrCellToCreate = 3`

`numRow = 2`

`newTable.Cell(numRow, 1).Split 1, nbAttrCellToCreate`

This solution works and provides the wished output, It allows to split the desired row into multiple cells
however it doesn't work when the change tracking option is active and I receive the following error once creating the table:

The required collection member does not exist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEP4c.png)

// The line of code which throws an error is the following

`newTable.Cell(curRow, curCol).Range.Text = fieldInfoList(cnt).Prefix & valSep & " " & fieldInfoList(cnt).defaultValue`

It seems that the split function for the newTable.Cell(2,1) which allows to divide the row into three cells has not been executed, which makes the newTable.Cell(2,2) and newTable.Cell(2,3) non-existent members of the collection

Question: Is there a function/method other than "Split" which allows to divide the row into multiple cells?

Thank you for your help!

I've tried the following solution which allows to split the desired row (numRow) into a specific number of cells (nbAttrCellToCreate):

`nbAttrCellToCreate = 3`

`numRow = 2`

`newTable.Cell(numRow, 1).Split 1, nbAttrCellToCreate`

Expected Result: the second row is divided into 3 cells

Obtained Result when change tracking is activated in Word: The split function has not been executed, the row has not been divided into cells, only the first cell is available.

Comment: Can your `Split` code turn off track changes before performing the split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell splitting functions when the change tracking is activated in Word. However, it will display a pop-up warning message box. You can get rid of the message box by setting `DisplayAlerts` to False. Please try it.

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim newTable As Table
    Dim nbAttrCellToCreate, numRow, i
    Set newTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    nbAttrCellToCreate = 3
    numRow = 2
    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
    newTable.Cell(numRow, 1).Split 1, nbAttrCellToCreate
    Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
    For i = 1 To 3
        newTable.Cell(numRow, i).Range.Text = i
    Next
End Sub
```

> https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/office/vba/api/word.cell.split?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461